# EF Core: Can I Use `.HasConversion()` For A SQL Float To C# Decimal Conversion?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have various existing SQL tables that have `float` columns that retain prices and I need to load them into C# `decimal` properties

After reading up on the `.HasConversion()` and `.HasColumnType()` methods, I thought I could read a SQL float *(which EF Core should know is a float because of `.HasColumnType()` and intern translates that to a `double`)* then convert it to a C# decimal using the `.HasConversion()` method; then vice-versa for writing back.

Have I misunderstood or am I misusing the methods?

---

Context `OnModelCreating`

```
entity.Property(e => e.Price) // <-- decimal field
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnName("PREFIX-Price")
    .HasColumnType("float")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("((0))")
    .HasConversion(
        v => Decimal.ToDouble(v),
        v => Convert.ToDecimal(v)
    )
```

After running something like:

```
var x = myContext.TableName.Select(x => x.Price);
```

I get the following exception:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Decimal'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDecimal(int i)
lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
```

I wouldn't expect it to call `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()` but rather fetch the float/double.

In the end, can I do what I'm trying to do?

---

Extra info:

(Although obvious) if I were to call the below then it works fine but this isn't really feasible as I/others could forget or not realise, plus the workload!

```
var x = myContext.TableName.Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Price));
```

Comment: Is a database migration not an option? Personally I would migrate the SQL data to the correct data type and then scaffold my models to match the correct state. Not doing so will lead to side effects.

Comment: Unfortunately not, 80-90% of the site is hosted in classic asp (real old-school!). I tried it on a small table that was only used in a couple of pages and it had some... side effects. Each instance of the field in the old classic asp had to be encased in `CDBL()`. I'm trying to get them to migrate to NET CORE but they want to keep all the back end functionality that has been custom added to the site.

Comment: Have you had a look at the value conversions documentation in EF Core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: Make a note that although what you're tying to do is possible, when writing to the database there will be precision loss. (I know it pretty obvious but I feel like I should say it anyway)

Comment: Also note that there is no built in converter for float to decimal so you'll have to define one.

Comment: @glenn223 what version of EF Core are you using? Also, are there other properties or entities with a decimal CLR type that maps to a float in db? Pretty sure this would work with just `entity.Property(e => e.Price).HasColumnType("float");`

Comment: @KieranDevlin - Yes, I've read the documentation. I'm hoping to convince them to migrate and then once the site is using only NET Core switch the SQL columns then. Final comment, I thought that's what I was doing with the `HasConversion` method

Comment: @JanPaoloGo - I'm running `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "2.2.0"`. There are no working properties in the `.NET Core` project. However, it works fine in an old `.NET Framework` project *(different dependency)* that was briefly started before the switch to Core

Comment: SQL Server's "float" is double, to keep things clear. A double can't be converted to decimal because its value range is much larger; `double.MaxValue` is `1,79769313486232E+308`, `decimal.MaxValue` "only" `79228162514264337593543950335`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create your own Value Converter like so:

```
var converter = new ValueConverter<decimal, double>(
    v => (double)v,
    v => (decimal)v
);
```

and then use it in the fluent API configuration:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<EntityType>()
    .Property(e => e.FeildName)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

Comment: Tried your code exactly. Sorry, didn't work. Though it might with it being a `float to decimal` conversion and me doing a `double to decimal`, but no luck

Comment: Sorry my mistake, try it with double. I've just created a console app to reproduce this and I manage to convert it fine so if you would like me to send you the repo, I can. I've updated the answer to reflect the correct type.

Comment: I just tried changing it to a decimal plus moving it out of the inline entity model (like mine) to the chained call (like yours) and still no luck. If you could send the repo, please. One quick question is your `e.FieldName` a decimal property? Just want to make sure as my property is `public decimal Price { get; set; }`

Comment: Yeah `FeildName` is of type decimal and the SQL schema that it maps to is of type float.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, the demo was on my work laptop. https://gitlab.com/KieranDevvs/efvalueconversiontest Hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196031/discussion-between-kieran-devlin-and-glenn223).